# SqlDirect Delphi XE4 TLS 1.2

Tags: delphi, tls1.2, delphi-xe4

We have developed a Delphi app on windows 10. We use sqldirect to connect to sql server 2017. Is it possible to use sqldirect with Tls 1.2? Or set the provider to msoledbsql?

Comment: Sqldirect seems old to me, why not use the built-in TADOxxx components? If you use the native client (recent version) then you have tls 1.2 support out of the box...

Comment: I agree with you, but rewriting it seems to be out of the question.

Comment: Then ask Sqldirect support?